# NotSupportedException when I'm using a method in the where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm using nHibernate 3.2.0.4000. I wrote this query using nHibernate.Linq

```
var entities = (from t in this.Session.Query<Task>()
                where NotIn(t, role.Tasks)
                select t).ToList();
```

Here's the definition of the method `NotIn()`

```
private bool NotIn(Task t, IEnumerable<TaskDto> tasks)
{
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        if (t.Name == task.Name) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I'm executing this query, I've got an `NotSupportedException` error:

```
Boolean NotIn(Probel.NDoctor.Domain.DAL.Entities.Task, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Probel.NDoctor.Domain.DTO.Objects.TaskDto])
```

I found a *non Linq* solution that is less readable but I still want to, at least, understand why it is impossible to build a Linq query like this.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You probably get this because LINQ doesn't know how to convert your method into SQL. You can tell it how, but I think that involves quite a bit of work, using Expression Trees.

Comment: Would something like `where !role.Tasks.Contains(t.Name)` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to translate `NotIn` to nHibernate SQL query using expression tree.

[nhibernate linq provider extension](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.in/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html)  is a good starting point.

[this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318177/Creating-In-and-NotIn-extension-methods-for-NHiber) has `In` and `NotIn` extension method for nHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in Linq is ultimately translated to SQL query by nhibernate. You can not use a method which could not be translated into SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate cannot decompile and then parse your code to get valid SQL.
There is no way to generate an sql statement from your method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use:

```
var entities = (from t in this.Session.Query<Task>()
                where !role.Tasks.Any(rt => rt.Name == t.Name)
                select t).ToList();
```

Comment: Still the NotSupportedException, which is normal considering the other answers about translation of a Linq expression into SQL